# Sequence of bounded integrable functions converging pointwise to non integrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

I want to find a sequence of functions $f_n$ converging to $f$ pointwise, where all of the $f_n$'s are bounded in magnitude (say by $1$) and integrable on $[−1, 1]$, but $f$ is
not integrable on $[−1, 1]$. I was thinking about using $f(x) =  \sin\left(\frac{1}{x - 1}\right)$ and $f_n(x) = f\left(x - \frac{1}{n}\right)$, but I'm not sure whether or not $f(x)$ is actually integrable or not on $[-1,1]$, and also $f_n$ only converges pointwise to $f$ on $[-1,1)$ since $f(1)$ is undefined. Is there a better example?

Comment: Integrable in the sense of Lebesgue, or in the sense of Riemann?

Comment: @Starfall Riemann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic function of the rational numbers in $ [-1, 1] $ is not a Riemann integrable function, and is clearly the pointwise limit of bounded integrable functions.

In your example, $ f(x) $ is not defined at $ 1 $; and no matter how you define it at $ 1 $, it will only be discontinuous at $ 1 $, thus it will be integrable.

Comment: I thought about using that as $f$ as well, but how is it the pointwise limit of bounded intebrable functions?

Comment: @ihmth Pick an enumeration of the rationals in the interval, say $ q_1, q_2, \ldots $; and define $ f_1 $ to be $ 1 $ at $ q_1 $ and $ 0 $ elsewhere, define $ f_2 $ to be $ 1 $ at $ q_1, q_2 $ and $ 0 $ elsewhere... What is the limit of this sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Let $q_1, q_2, \dots$ be the rationals in $[-1,1].$ For $n\in \mathbb N,$ let $f_n=\mathbb 1_{\{q_1,\dots , q_n\}}.$ Then each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1],$ each $f_n$ is bounded by $1$ in magnitude, and $f_n \to \mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q\cap [-1,1]}$ pointwise everywhere in $[-1,1].$ However, $\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q\cap [-1,1]}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[-1,1].$